# Given n numbers How to find out a set of numbers whose sum equal to a certain given number

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, combinatorics, sets

I am given an list of numbers and A number-s. I need to find out the collection(s) of numbers from the list of numbers whose sum corresponds to the given number s.

```
for example - the given set is [2,8,3] and given integer 9
Then I can tell {3,3,3} or {3,2,2,2} can be the required sets.
```

Unfortunately I cannot figure out the best approach (with best time complexity)..
As I tried to do it using nested loops which naturally results into huge time complexity.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to find all such possible collections, or any one collection? The former is harder, since their number can grow rather quickly.

Comment: Also useful would be limits or estimates on the length of the list and on the numbers themselves.

Comment: Yes I need to find all such possible combination..Actually the main problem is big I have just given here a part Because there I have to compare between such combinations and select the best one  @Gassa

Comment: If you want to select the best one, that doesn't mean you need all of them. You only need to find combinations that _might_ be the best. In that case, better tell us which combination you want. See the example in my answer with gazillions of solutions

Comment: You are basically looking for the solution space for a linear diophantine equation.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is based on [knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Consider the list elements $a_1$, $a_2$, $\ldots$, $a_n$ in any fixed order.
Calculate the following boolean function: $f (k, t)$ is true if it is possible to have the sum of exactly $t$ from some subset of $a_1$, $a_2$, $\ldots$, $a_k$, and false otherwise.
Here, $k$ spans from $0$ to $n$, inclusive, and $t$ goes from $0$ to $s$: we don't need larger sums.

The calculation can be performed in $O (n \cdot s)$ using dynamic programming.
Just observe that $f (k, t) = f (k - 1, t)\mathrm{~or~} f (k, t - a_k)$: for the element $a_k$ and for every possible target sum $t$, we either drop the element from consideration, or take it into our sum.
In the latter case, we must have the chance to take it again, hence the transition to $(k, t - a_k)$ instead of $(k - 1, t - a_k)$.

Now, knowing which $(k, t)$ pairs are possible and which are not, we can recursively construct all possible answers in $O((n + s) \cdot R)$, where $R$ is the number of answers.
Indeed, descend from $(n, s)$ down to $(0, 0)$.
When we are at $(k, t)$, we can see whether $(k - 1, t)$ and $(k, t - a_k)$ are possible, and descend only into the possible branches.
As every descent takes at most $n + s$ steps, finding $R$ possible answers will happen in $(n + s) \cdot R$ time.
Actually, it will be faster since some descent paths share a common start, and some $a_k$ are greater than $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Finding *all* collections will generally take exponential time since there is an exponential number of solutions. For example, take { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } and sum = 1000: Take any number of tens as long as the sum stays ≤ 1000, add any number of nines as long as the sum stays ≤ 1000, add any numbers of eights, sevens, ..., twos, finally add as many ones as needed.

To find *one* solution I would sort the numbers in ascending order and focus on gcd's. If gcd (x, y) = 1 then every number ≥ (x-1)(y-1) can be produced using these two numbers. In your case, with gcd(2,3) = 1, every number ≥ 1*2 = 2 can be produced which already solves your problem.

To illustrate why you don't need *all* combinations to find the best one: Take my example, and we define the "best" combination as the one with the smallest number of numbers added. With quadrillions of combinations solving the problem, I tell you out of my head that the optimal one is "100 times the number 10".